# Attempt to read property <property> on null

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, sdk

Есть 3 проекта

1. Лаунчер (.NET Framework 4.8)
2. Библиотека (.NET Framework 4.8)
3. Программа (.NET Core 7.0.9, .NET SDK 7)

##### Общая логика

Запуск **Программы** осуществляется через **Лаунчер**. **Лаунчер** и **Программа** используют методы RestAPI, описанные в **Библиотеке**. В некоторых методах одним из обязательных полей является идентификатор компьютера (далее `hid_hash`).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

##### Суть проблемы

В **Лаунчере**, при добавлении в тело запроса `hid_hash` все проходит гладко, однако при вызове того же метода в **Программе** из той же **Библиотеки** и аналогично добавленном `hid_hash` вылезает ошибка.

```
Attempt to read property `hid_hash` on null
```

Рабочий блок в **Лаунчере**, реализовано внутри **Лаунчера**

```
var hid_hash = Program.SystemHash;
var response = new ApiClient().SendRequest(
    method: Method.POST,
    route: "login",
    body: new { email, password, hid_hash } // <- OK
).ToJObject();
```

Нерабочий блок в **Программе**, реализовано внутри **Библиотеки**

```
var hid_hash = Information.SystemHash; // hid_hash не пустой, проверялось
var pathToLogs = bool.Parse((string)new ApiClient().SendRequest(
    method: RestSharp.Method.POST,
    route: "hash-verify",
    body: new { hid_hash }, // <- "Attempt to read property `hid_hash` on null"
    accessToken: cipher.Decode(args[2])
).ToJObject().GetValue("verify")) ? cipher.Decode(args[3]) : "";
```

Хочу отметить, что проводились тесты по выводу hid_hash и сериализованномого объекта на строне клиента:

```
string hid_hash = Information.SystemHash;
Console.WriteLine($"v1: {hid_hash}");
Console.WriteLine($"v2: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { hid_hash }, Formatting.Indented)}");
var pathToLogs = bool.Parse((string)new ApiClient().SendRequest(
    method: RestSharp.Method.POST,
    route: "hash-verify",
    body: new { hid_hash },
    accessToken: cipher.Decode(args[2])
).ToJObject().GetValue("verify")) ? cipher.Decode(args[3]) : "";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай прикрепляю метод `SendRequest`:

```
internal JToken SendRequest(
    Method method,
    string route,
    object body = null,
    string accessToken = null
)
{
    IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(
        resource: new Uri(uriString: $"{API_URL}/{route}"),
        method: method
    ).AddHeader(
        name: "Content-Type",
        value: "application/json"
    ).AddHeader(
        name: "Accept",
        value: "application/json"
    );

    // Здесь происходит сериализация объекта в строку
    if (body != null)
        restRequest.AddJsonBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body));

    if (accessToken != null)
        restRequest.AddHeader(
            name: "Authorization",
            value: $"Bearer {accessToken}"
        );

    IRestResponse response = RestClient.Execute(restRequest);

    try
    {
        JObject responseJson = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

        if (!responseJson.TryGetValue("success", out JToken isSuccess) || !(bool)isSuccess)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                throw new WebException("Access denied.");
            else
                throw new WebException((string)responseJson.GetValue("message"));
        }

        return responseJson.TryGetValue("data", out JToken responseData)
            ? responseJson["data"]
            : responseData;
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to process server response.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is WebException || ex is NullReferenceException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return null;
}
```

У меня складывается впечатление, что один и тот же код по-разному воспроизводится на разных платформах, хоть и вызывается из одной библиотеки (она специально была сделана для одинакового использования). Самое интересное - на моей машине оба блока отрабатывают нормально, на машине клиента (человека) - падает.

##### Конфигурация моей машины

```
ПАКЕТ SDK ДЛЯ .NET:
 Version:   7.0.306
 Commit:    f500069cb7

Среда выполнения:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19045
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.9
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       8e9a17b221

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.416 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.306 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

##### Конфигурация машины клиента

```
ПАКЕТ SDK ДЛЯ .NET:
 Version:   7.0.400
 Commit:    73bf45718d

Среда выполнения:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.10
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       a6dbb800a4

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.306 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

Comment: Вы сами себя запутали различными библиотеками и обертками... Возьмите чистый `HttpClient` и через него отправьте то, что вы отправляете при помощи `RestSharp`, если все пройдет без проблем, то дело в библиотеке, если нет, качайте Fiddler и отлавливайте запросы, смотрите чем они отличаются и почему. Сейчас вы дали портянку кода и просите в ней разобраться, где часть портянки попросту отсутствует и приходится гадать что там да как, согласитесь, как-то не ок. Хотите нашей помощи, отбросьте тогда все, напишите чистый код без оберток, и прикладывайте как "самодостаточный код".